# Angular Unit Tests are working locally but killed in GitLab CI using Karma

Tags: angular, unit-testing, gitlab, karma-jasmine, gitlab-ci

Issue in running Unit tests using Karma for Angular project in GitLab CI, after the Unit Tests run using: `npm run ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox` The result is killed:

*16 11 2021 06:49:26.978:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox with concurrency unlimited*

*16 11 2021 06:49:26.986:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.*

*16 11 2021 06:50:12.722:INFO [Chrome Headless 96.0.4664.45 (Linux x86_64)]: Connected on socket Kr5liuJXMmWTQGbpAAAB with id 63497465*

*Killed*

*Cleaning up file based variables*

karma.conf.js:

```
    module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
      jasmine: {
        random: false
      }
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/daiconnect'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
    singleRun: true,
    restartOnFileChange: false,
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--disable-gpu',
          //'--headless',
          '--enable-logging',
          '--no-default-browser-check',
          '--no-first-run',
          '--disable-default-apps',
          '--disable-popup-blocking',
          '--disable-translate',
          '--disable-background-timer-throttling',
          '--disable-renderer-backgrounding',
          '--disable-device-discovery-notifications',
          '--remote-debugging-port=9222',
          '--disable-web-security'
        ]
      }
    },
    captureTimeout: 210000,
    browserDisconnectTolerance: 3,
    browserDisconnectTimeout: 210000,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 210000
  });
};
```

Comment: Try adding the `--disable-dev-shm-usage` flag.

Comment: @sytech thanks but it didn't work still the process killed.